# How to use control statements on a methods? if possible

Tags: java, switch-statement

I don't know how to say

if money(); < 1000 and house(); is == small print your poor

or

if money(); >=1000 and < 5000 and house(); is == to normal to print your ok, your too rich

```
package ArrayTest;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by quwi on 02/12/2017.
 */`enter code here`
public class Happyness {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        house();
//        money();
        comparison();


    }

    private static void house() {


        //       getting user input and using the switch statement to see the size
        //       of their house

        System.out.println("Please enter the size of your house ");
        String cap = scanner.next();

        switch (cap) {
            case "small":
                System.out.println("you have a small house it means your poor");
                break;
            case "normal":
                System.out.println("your house normal, it mean your not poor nor rich");
                break;
            case "large":
                System.out.println("your house is big it means your rich");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("please choose between: small, normal or large");
                break;
        }
    }


    private static void money() {

        System.out.println("please enter a number");
        int wage = scanner.nextInt();
        if (wage < 1000) {
            System.out.println("your poor");
        } else if (wage >= 1000 && wage < 5000) {
            System.out.println("your not poor, your OK");
        } else if (wage > 5000) {
            System.out.println("your rich, Give me money");
        } else {
            System.out.println("please enter a number nothing else");
        }
    }

    private static void comparison() {


        System.out.println("please enter a number");
        int decision = scanner.nextInt();

        switch (decision) {
            case 1:
                money();
                break;
            case 2:
                house();
                break;
            case 3:
                money();
                house();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Please choose 1, 2 or 3");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the code you've posted here?

Comment: To make a decision based on both `money()` and `house()` they both need to return a value. In `comaprison()` you can have something like `int amount = money()`

Answer (score 0):

Use return value from both to compare.

```
private static String money() {

    System.out.println("please enter a number");
    int wage = scanner.nextInt();
    if (wage < 1000) {
        return "poor";
    } else if (wage >= 1000 && wage < 5000) {
        return "ok";
    } else if (wage > 5000) {
        return "rich";
    } else {
        //ask for input again or exit, whatever
    }
}
```

Do same for the `house()`. Then, compare the return values from both in another method.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working, I added the returns but it doesn't seem to be printing the "poor", "ok" or "rich"

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working, I added the returns but it doesn't seem to be printing the "poor", "ok" or "rich". The last return is also confusing. it says return required a String Found an int.